# Can I set a state from another class?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I was wondering if there any way to set the state of this selectedIndex variable from another class?
Because I'm trying to change the page on the navigation bar when I press a button from another screen, I'm really sorry for wasting your time but I'm kinda new in flutter?

```
class Nav_bar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Nav_barState createState() => _Nav_barState();
}

class _Nav_barState extends State<Nav_bar> {


  void changeIndex() {
    setState(() {
      selectedIndex = 2;
    });
  }

  int selectedIndex = 0;


  final _pageOptions = [
    Search_vehicles(),
    Chats(),
    Chats(),
    Chats(),
  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: Center(
        child: _pageOptions[selectedIndex],
      ),

      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        
   
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 20),
            child: GNav(
              
                tabs: [
                  GButton(
                   
                  ),
                  GButton(
                   
                  ),
                  GButton(
                    
                  ),
                  GButton(
                    
                  ),
                ],
                selectedIndex: selectedIndex,

                onTabChange: (index) {
                 setState(() {
                   selectedIndex = index;
                 });
                }),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Pass `ChangeIndex` as an argument to the other class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can set a state from another class. You can use the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) and set and get the selected index from anywhere in your application.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class IndexProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  int get selectedIndex => this._selectedIndex;

  set setSelectedIndex(int value) {
    _selectedIndex = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

You can read more about the app state management from [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).